# Why Visual Studio Team System 2008 try to check out all solution's projects while debugging?

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2008, vcs-checkout

We develop using VS2008 solution that have about 26 project that's added to Team System Source control.
The problem is: sometime when developer try to debug a project, VS check out all projects before debugging, we don't know Why this happen especially if we close all vs and try again the problem not appear ... Is any know how to solve this issue ?

Comment: Out of interest, what is the change it makes to the project files themselves?

Answer (score 2):

That's how it is. I hate it too. The best you could do is configure Visual Studio to ask every time before it checks out a file so that the developer is being warned of what is happening behind the scenes:

[image]

Comment: but i don't want to show check out prompt for each time i want to check out ... is there any other solution ?